Are the proposed truth tables for the rules correct?
I'm trying to propose truth tables for the following two rules which are originally defined on page 5 in this paper:
Title: An abstract framework for argumentation with structured arguments
Author: Henry Prakken
Journal: Argument & Computation
volume: 1
Pages: 93--124
Year: 2010
Strict rule is of the form $\phi_1,......, \phi_n \rightarrow \phi$, informally meaning that if $ \phi_1,.....,\phi_n$ hold, then without exception it holds that $\phi$.
Defeasible rule is of the form $\phi_1,......, \phi_n \Rightarrow \phi$, informally meaning that if $ \phi_1,.....,\phi_n$ hold, then it presumably holds that $\phi$.
Now, if A is the antecedent and B is the consequent, are the truth tables for the strict and defeasible rules, shared below, valid?
      Strict Defeasible
A  B  A->B   A=>B
T  T  T      T
T  F  N/A    T (presumably holds)
F  T  T      T 
F  F  T      T 

If they are not correct, kindly rectify them with explanations.

We ask that you provide a full reference/citation for the paper you are asking about (e.g., title, authors, where published, etc.), both so that the question continues to make sense even if the link stops working, and so that others with a similar question about the paper can find this page by websearch on the paper title.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/
